# ZAP Scanning Report - Wildcard Directive,style-src unsafe-inline,script-src unsafe-inline

Tags: zap

[image] When scanning using OWASP ZAP, the report shows the following as medium risk:

1. Wildcard Directive
2. style-src unsafe-inline
3. script-src unsafe-inline

How can I fixed this issue on my server?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at everything that ZAP is reporting? There should be a lot more information than this.

For the unsafe-inline findings you'll need to remove those elements from your CSP and move all of the inline styles and scripts into external files from the HTML. I'd focus on  the inline scripts as they are more concerning.

Comment: Thats just part of the data for this issue - there should be a solution and potentially other info. But in any case, your CSP contains 'unsafe-inline' in the script-src element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src in order to be ableto remove it you'll need to move all of your inline scripts into separate JS files.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing Wildcard Directive issue in CSP header set all the headers required like this
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; media-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; manifest-src 'none'; worker-src 'none'; prefetch-src 'none'; form-action 'none' " always;